# How to add a field to a projection from another table?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

## Models

I have 3 models; `Catalog`, `Product` and `Translation`.
`Product` has an FK to `Catalog`.
`Translation` has an FK to `Product`.

However, `Product` does not have a `Bag` of `Translations`.
If I want to get the translations, I have to do so with a "manual" query a la
`QueryOver<Translation>().Where(x=> x.Product = product)`

## Current Situation

The query I am working with at the moment is this:

```
Catalog catalogAlias = null;
Product productAlias = null;

return _session
    .QueryOver(() => catalogAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => catalogAlias.ProductList, () => productAlias)
    .Select(
        Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property(() => catalogAlias.Id))
        .Add(Projections.Property(() => productAlias.Name))
        )
    .Future<object[]>();
```

## What I want to do

Now I need to add the translation to each returned `object[]`. So I would need something like this:

```
Catalog catalogAlias = null;
Product productAlias = null;
Translation translationAlias = null;

return _session
    .QueryOver(() => catalogAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => catalogAlias.ProductList, () => productAlias)
    .Select(
        Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property(() => catalogAlias.Id))
        .Add(Projections.Property(() => productAlias.Name))

        // This here vvv
        .Add(Projections.Property(()=> 
            _session.QueryOver(() => translationAlias)
                .Where(()=> translationAlias.Product == productAlias)
                .SingleOrDefault()
                .Name
        ))
        // This here ^^^

        )
    .Future<object[]>();
```

Of course, if that would have worked, I wouldn't ask this question. This throws
`System.ArgumentException : Unrecognised method call in expression value`

## Question

How can I get a `Translation`,
based on a property of `Product`,
which is part of a list of products in `Catalog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use `Projections.SubQuery`. Something like:

```
.Add(Projections.SubQuery(
            QueryOver.Of(() => translationAlias)
                .Where(() => translationAlias.Product == productAlias)
                .Take(1)
                .Select(tr => tr.Name)
))
```